# How to get the element height correctly with jquery

Tags: jquery, height, bxslider

I have a Bxslider with elements and i need to trigger in some way one lelemt height and depending on that give some other padding to that element.Here is my code which is not working properly

```
jQuery('.servicesmobilecatswrap').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    pager :false,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    nextSelector: '#servicecat_next',
    touchEnabled : false,
    onSliderLoad : function () {  
        var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
        if(windowWidth < 480){
            jQuery('.servicesmobiletitle').each(function(){
                if(jQuery(this).outerHeight() < 85){
                    //alert('yes');
                    jQuery(this).css({'padding-top':'62px'});
                }
            });
        }
    },
    onSlideBefore : function () {  
        var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
        if(windowWidth < 480){
            jQuery('.servicesmobiletitle').each(function(){
                if(jQuery(this).outerHeight() < 85){
                    //alert('yes');
                    jQuery(this).css({'padding-top':'62px'});
                }
            });
        }
    }, 
    onSlideAfter : function () {  
        var windowWidth = jQuery(window).width();
        if(windowWidth < 480){
            jQuery('.servicesmobiletitle').each(function(){
                if(jQuery(this).outerHeight() < 85){
                    //alert('yes');
                    jQuery(this).css({'padding-top':'62px'});
                }
            });
        }
    },
prevSelector: '#servicecat_prev', 
nextText: '',
prevText: '' 
});
```

Here is the HTMl

```
<div class="servicemobilecatitem">
         <div class="servicesmobiletitle">Branding</div>
          <div class="servicesmobiletext">hghfghfgh</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should go with position(), http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: the issue is that the statement if(jQuery(this).outerHeight() < 85 is not working properly, seems it is right but it is not working properly @NeerajSharma

Comment: See my edit @NeerajSharma

Comment: so what else you need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98540/discussion-between-neeraj-sharma-and-anahit-dev).

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this on your site and found, 'this' have its object,

[image: on your site]

Comment: am also cant underdtand why it didnt work properly, if you will have a look you will see that the padding applies to all title items so if is not working